# Blender game bug with Pause menus

Tags: game-engine, scene

I got very weird problem in my game which I am making. To make each level work correct with pause menus, I have made a pause menu for each of levels. I have set the sensors, controllers and actuators identic for each level, only with changing data about to which level switch...
[image: Level 1's Pause]
[image: Level 2's Pause]

As you see, evrything fits- evrything is identic in each pause menu, just level links are changed... But this Menu works in 1. level (Pause), but does not work in 2. Level (Pause2). Why is it like that and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you upload the .blend via Pasteall.com?

Comment: Can I use dropbox instead? Pasteall works so slow and it is actually pasteall.org...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmchrth4qgbm3fl/Labyrinth.blend?dl=0 And here are the rules: Please don't ise it as yours(do not public or modify with your name).

Comment: No any answer?:(